# How was this equation derived for a L-C negative resistance oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, negative-resistance

I'm looking over some old notes and saw this series of equations for a L-C oscillator. The first step is just writing a KCL equation for the circuit:
$$
\frac{V}{-R}+sCV+\frac{V}{sL+r}=0
$$

Where \$s=j\omega \$

The next step shows:
$$
s^2LC+s(Cr-\frac{L}{R})+1-\frac{r}{R} =0
$$
How was this equation derived from the original KCL equation?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4NROz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Divide by V (it just falls out), multiply both sides with (SL+r), order resulting terms as a polynomial in S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original has V as a common factor. If we assume there can be some other V than zero, the V can be divided off. Then multiple both sides with sL+r and reorder the terms. That's a formula which shows the possible s. If the solved s happens to be complex and have positive real part the oscillator really can oscillate. The limit is imaginary s, then the amplitude stays and the oscillation is pure sinusoidal.

Comment: That's it, thank you! Quick followup, how was sL+r "chosen" in order to derive the formula necessary to show the roots?

Comment: Multiplying the denominator off gives a  2nd order equation which has well known formula for the roots. To use that formula one must have form "a 2nd order polynomial = zero"

Comment: Awesome, thanks!